# Php MySQL Data from a class

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What I am trying to do here is to get all the categories from the table categories. Then print them out in a checkbox.

If I had code it a few categories it works fine.

But when I add in the database/sql info nothing prints out.  Any idea on what I am doing wrong here?

**Users.php**

```
<?php
     //users Class
     class Users {
    function get_categories()
    {
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT category FROM categories';
        //Hardcoded information
        //$result = array ('a' => 'Human','b' => 'Animal');

        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php
    include('class/users.php');
    //User object.
    $new_photo = new Users;
     ?>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Categroies</label>
      <?php
      $categories = $new_photo->get_categories();
        foreach ($categories->fetch_array() as $cate) {
           echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=\"category[]\" value='$cate' />$cate<br>"; 
   }
      ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: try a print_r($result) in the Users class for starters

Comment: What you are using for execute this query? I pretty sure this method `query()` doesn't return an array. And please, edit your question and insert the error information, and `print_r` like @Dukeatcoding said.

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What DB class are you using when doing your query ? The result of  `$db->query($query)` is probably not an array that you can loop throught.

If mysqli, you must loop using the `$result->fetch_array()`

Changing the line to `foreach ($categories->fetch_array() as $cate) {` should work or outputing the array directly from your function using `return $result->fetch_array();`

Comment: When I added that it only brings out 1 record twice.  That database has 18 records in it.  This is strange.

Comment: Did you add the `fetch_array()` in your function or in your loop? it is strange that you only get 2 record. Another thing that could help is to `print_r($cate)` in your loop to see the complete row.

Comment: Yeah I get 2 records when I did this.

Comment: For some reason I am thinking that it is not putting the recordset into an array.  Just giving the first record in the recordset.

Comment: You didnt answer my question. Where did you put the `fetch_array()`. In your Users.php at the return statement ? or in the Upload.php in your loop ? You only need to place it at one place. Can you repaste your code ? maybe something has changed.

Comment: I put it up in the Upload.php page.  I also put the change I made in the code above.

Comment: Well.. i have no idea why you still have only 2 record. maybe try to `print_r($categories->fetch_array())` before the foreach loop. It should display the whole array that your query resulted. Maybe this will give you more information to debug ?

Comment: in the users.php page I added this in there and all of the records printed out.  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['category'];
}  So it is coming through.  It is being lost I feel from Users.php -> Upload.php

Comment: Well.. one thing you could do is to output the array directly. Remove the `->fetch_array()` form your foreach loop in Upload.. And edit your return line in User to this : `return mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli in database class, then return using mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

```
    class Users{
    function get_categories()
    {
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT category FROM categories';
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am thinking that it is not putting the recordset into an array. Just giving the first record in the recordset.

Comment: Can you test one more thing. Instead of using the global $db, please use the direct connection in that function.